# How do I draw a QFont anti-aliased when the OS has anti-alias turned off?

Tags: qt, antialiasing, qpainter, qpixmap

When I use a `QPainter` to `drawText` onto a `QPixmap` using a `QFont`, it appears anti-aliased when the OS has anti-alias enabled, but not when it doesn't even though **I am explicitly setting render hints of the painter and strategy of the font**:

```
QPainter painter(&pixmap);
painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::NoSubpixelAntialias); // I do not want clear-type
```

I know the OS (Windows 7 in this case) is capable of drawing anti-aliased text when anti-alias text is turned off at the OS level because visual studio does this.

**How do I get Qt to override this OS's anti-alias setting?**

*Search term: antialias*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure you add `QFont::PreferAntialias` to your `font.setStyleStrategy` call. Like so:

```
font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::NoSubpixelAntialias | QFont::PreferAntialias);
```

Comment: The correct code is font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::PreferAntialias);